# Reddit API not returning NSFW posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reddit

When i put the link into the browser i am getting results, just not when im making a call from my app. I first assumed this was something by reddit but if so then why would i be able to see the data from the browser.
Below are two example links, One works and one doesnt - the only difference is one is from a NSFW sub.

```
axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/search.json?q=example&restrict_sr=true')


axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/search.json?q=cat&limit=1&sort=top&restrict_sr=true&after=null')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include the `include_over_18` parameter.

Try `axios.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/search.json?q=example&restrict_sr=true&include_over_18=on')`

Comment: That worked, Thanks a ton. Where did you find this? I couldnt see this in the documentation

Comment: It is indeed missing from the documentation. I found it looking for why reddit might not be returning results from a NSFW subreddit.